# Continuing test execution in junit4 even when one of the asserts fails

Tags: java, junit4

I have my existing framework built up using Jfunc which provides a facility to continue exection even when one of the asserts  in the test case fails. Jfunc uses junit 3.x framework. But now we are migrating to junit4 so I can't use Jfunc anymore and have replaced it with junit 4.10 jar. 
Now the problem is since we have extensively used jfunc in our framework, and with junit 4 we want to make our code continue the execution even when one of the asserts fails in a test case.
Does anyone has any suggestion/idea for this, i know in junit the tests needs to be more atomic i.e. one assert per test case but we can't do that in our framework for some reason.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can do this using an [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule.

To use it, first add the rule as a field in your test class:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    //...tests...
}
```

Then replace your asserts with calls to `collector.checkThat(...)`.

e.g.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    collector.checkThat("a", equalTo("b"));
    collector.checkThat(1, equalTo(2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply chris.
It worked and continued after the first failure (i.e. collector.checkThat(10, CoreMatchers.equalTo(11))).
But the problem is that I want it mark the test as failed even if one of the checks fails.
Currently after executing the above test, the test is marked as passed. I want it to fail and show the stacktrace on the failure line (something similar to when an asserttion fails).

Comment: That's strange. I just tried the code I wrote in my answer, and it worked as expected. The test fails, and it prints out the stack trace of each failing assertion. Here is the full test code and the output that I got, running the test from IntelliJ: https://gist.github.com/2419626

Comment: Oh...my bad, I just forget to add the rule and it caused all the chaos.....sorry for the confusion and thx a lot for the post.

Comment: Just FYI, you can append message to the `checkThat` method by simply adding a String as the first parameter. **But this method only supported after 4.10 (including)**.

Comment: Hi, does it mark all the failed steps as 'Failed' too?

Answer (score 24):

I use the ErrorCollector too but also use assertThat and place them in a try catch block.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

@Test
public void calculatedValueShouldEqualExpected() {
    try {
        assertThat(calculatedValue(), is(expected));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        collector.addError(t);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [assertj - soft assertion](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-soft-assertions)

```
@Test
public void testCollectErrors(){
   SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();
   softly.assertThat(true).isFalse();
   softly.assertThat(false).isTrue();
   // Don't forget to call SoftAssertions global verification !
   softly.assertAll();
}
```

Also exist other way to use it without manually invoke softly.assertAll();

1. [with rule](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-junit4-soft-assertions)
2. [with autoclosable](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-closeable-soft-assertions)
3. [Using the static assertSoftly method](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-assertSoftly-assertions)

Comment: As this works without try...catch and as intended by the lib-authors, I think this is the most canonical solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use try/finally blocks. This worked in my case:

```
...
try {
    assert(...)
} finally {
    // code to be executed after assert
}
...
```

Comment: You realize this question was posted 2 years ago and there's already a accepted answer?

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer just a general note, this site is not just about accepted answers.  The point is to help users who search for answers to find a solution to a problem.  Sometimes there are multiple approaches to solve a problem, and sometimes what works for one person might not work as well for another.

Comment: @nomistic fine, true enough.

Comment: I found that this answer only works if there is a single assert statement. Multiple asserts are not executed after the error is thrown.

Comment: @LydiaRalph: Yes, each assert needs its own try/finally block. This is not explained in the answer.

Comment: The question is about unit test assertions, not java language assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Try - catch, in "try" use the assertion, in "catch" add the possible error to collection.
Then throw the exception at the end of test, in tearDown().
So if there will be fail/error in assert, it will be catched and test will continue.
(The collection in example is static, you can also make new instance in setUp() for each @Test)

```
    public static List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        //some assert...
    }
    catch (AssertionError error) {
        errors.add(error.toString());
    }



    @After
    public void tearDown() {

        try {
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                throw new AssertionError(errors);
            }
        }
        finally {
            //empty list because it's static, alternatively make instance for each test in setUp()
            errors.clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own simple assertions class. Easy to extend with your use-cases:

```
public class MyEquals {

public static void checkTestSummary(MyTestSummary myTestSummary) {
    final List<MyTestResult> conditions = myTestSummary.getTestResults();
    final int total = conditions.size();

    final boolean isSuccessful = myTestSummary.isSuccessful();
    if (isSuccessful) {
        System.out.println(format("All [%s] conditions are successful!", total));
    } else {
        final List<MyTestResult> failedConditions = conditions.stream().filter(MyTestResult::isTestResult).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(format("\nNot yet.. [%s out of %s] conditions are failed", failedConditions.size(), total));
    }

    if (!isSuccessful) {
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            final MyTestResult myTestResult = conditions.get(i);
            if (myTestResult.isTestResult()) {
                System.out.println(format("  Success [%s of %s] => Expected %s Actual %s Good!", i + 1, total, myTestResult.getExpected(), myTestResult.getActual()));
            } else {
                System.out.println(format("!! Failed [%s of %s] => Expected %s Actual %s", i + 1, total, myTestResult.getExpected(), myTestResult.getActual()));
            }
        }
    }

    assertTrue(isSuccessful);
}

public static void myAssertEquals(MyTestSummary myTestSummary, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (checkEquals(expected, actual)) {
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        myTestSummary.addSuccessfulResult(expected, actual);
    } else {
        myTestSummary.addFailedResult(expected, actual);
        myTestSummary.setSuccessful(false);
    }
}

public static boolean checkEquals(Object value1, Object value2) {
    if (value1 == null && value2 == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (value1 != null && value2 == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (value1 == null && value2 != null) {
        return false;
    } else if (value1 != null && value2 != null) {
        return value1.equals(value2);
    }
    return false;
}

}

@Builder
@Value
public class MyTestResult {

    String expected;

    String actual;

    boolean testResult;

 }



@Data
public class MyTestSummary {

private boolean successful = true;

private List<MyTestResult> testResults = new ArrayList<>();

public MyTestSummary() {
}

public void addSuccessfulResult(Object expected, Object actual) {
    getTestResults().add(MyTestResult.builder()
        .expected(String.valueOf(expected))
        .actual(String.valueOf(actual))
        .testResult(true)
        .build()
    );
}

public void addFailedResult(Object expected, Object actual) {
    getTestResults().add(MyTestResult.builder()
        .expected(String.valueOf(expected))
        .actual(String.valueOf(actual))
        .testResult(false)
        .build()
    );
}
}
```

Usage in the junit test

```
@Test
public void testThat() {
    MyTestSummary myTestSummary = new MyTestSummary();
    myAssertEquals(myTestSummary, 10, 5 + 5);
    myAssertEquals(myTestSummary, "xxx", "x" + "x");
    checkTestSummary(myTestSummary);
}
```

Output:

```
Not yet.. [1 out of 2] conditions are failed
Success [1 of 2] => Expected 10 Actual 10 Good!
!! Failed [2 of 2] => Expected xxx Actual xx

 org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
 Expected :true
 Actual   :false
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is the observable pattern in conjunction with lambda expressions. You can use something like the above.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    private final List<Consumer<MyTestClass>> AFTER_EVENT = new ArrayList<>();

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        AFTER_EVENT.stream().forEach(c -> c.accept(this));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase() {
        //=> Arrange
        AFTER_EVENT.add((o) -> {
            // do something after an assertion fail.
        }));

        //=> Act

        //=> Assert
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```