# Junit assert.fail() method is getting stop the exectuion , Need to continue the execution and give result in the end

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testng

Scenario: There is an excel sheet, A column has 1000 records.. I need to verify whether all the values are equal or not.

Challenge : If I use assert.fail() method, when failure is occurring execution stops.

Required: But I want to continue the execution and give the result in the end. If any value is not matching, need to say test case is failed and print the non matching values.

Comment: Please check answer at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221891/continuing-test-execution-in-junit4-even-when-one-of-the-asserts-fails

Answer (score 1):

Keep adding those values to a Set. At the end if Set has more than one value (check the size) then print the values. This means all the values are not same. If the size is 1 then all values are same.

Comment: I have the logic for checking values are equal or not.. but my question is to continue the execution and give the result in the end. If any value is not matching, need to say test case is failed and print the non matching values

Answer (score 0):

You could be doing something like this:

```
Map<Whatever, Integer> unequalValues = new HashMap<>();
... iterate your rows; and for each row do
  unequalValues.put(valueFromRow, rowIndex);
```

In the end, you simply check if `unequalValues` contains more than one entry. If so, you can print all entries; including the row index/number.
And then, in the end, you call `fail()`

If you are only interested in the fact that you have non-equal values, but not in which row they are ... a Set instead of a Map would do, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through Excel comparing the current row's string, `testString`, to `expectedString`. Any time it doesn't match, add `testString` to `mismatches`. Once the Excel sheet has been fully tested, see if `mismatches` contains anything. If it does, print all the values inside `mismatches` and then use a JUnit `Assert` to fail the test.

```
String expectedString = "myTestString";
Set<String> mismatches = new HashSet<String>();
while (...) // loop through Excel rows
{
    String testString = getValueFromExcel();
    if (!testString.equals(expectedString))
    {
        mismatches.add(testString); // add any values that don't match to 'mismatches'
    }
}

if (mismatches.size() > 0)
{
    System.out.println(mismatches.size() + " mismatches were found:");
    // dump the mismatches
    for (String mismatch : mismatches)
    {
        System.out.println("  " + mismatch);
    }
}
// now throw a JUnit assert that the test failed
Assert.assertEquals(mismatches.size(), 0, "Verify that no mismatches were found");
```