# Show all failed Asserts of a List/String/Array

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to check that difference between two update_timestamp of a table is of 5 minutes. Using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaUpdateTimestamp.size() - 1; i++) {
        String updateTimeStampLeft = listaUpdateTimestamp.get(i);
        String updateTimeStampRight = listaUpdateTimestamp.get(i + 1);

Long diff = getDateDiff(updateTimeStampLeftDate, updateTimeStampRightDate, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

assertEquals(EXPECTED_TIME_DIFF, diff);
```

It only shows me just one failed assertion (Don't know if it's the biggest one, or just a random one), when I know there are more. Is there some way to make the app show me all failed asserts?

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: It's the first one. As soon as an assertion fails, the test is over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuing test execution in junit4 even when one of the asserts fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221891/continuing-test-execution-in-junit4-even-when-one-of-the-asserts-fails)

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys