# junit 5 run all assert even if there is failed one

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Is there any mechanism in JUnit 5 to run all assert in test even if assert in the middle failed?
For example:

```
@Test
public void unitForTest_SomeScenario_ShouldReturn() {

    //Arrange
    var myObj = myServ.getMyObj();
    //Act & Assert
    assertThat(myObj).isNotNull();
    assertThat(myObj.getName()).isEqualTo("Steve"); //failed assert
    assertThat(myObj.getLastName()).isEqualTo("Gates");
}
```

My intention is to run all asserts and track that failed is only second, but not the third and first.

Comment: You create three separate test cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuing test execution in junit4 even when one of the asserts fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221891/continuing-test-execution-in-junit4-even-when-one-of-the-asserts-fails)

Comment: @Joe no, sorry that question doesn't answers mine, because I want to use possibility of JUnit 5, and I knew that there is something like glything proposed

Comment: @Joe Proposing a JUnit 4 question as duplicate of a JUnit 5 question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel AFAICS, the same technique works in both.

Comment: @Joe rules don't exist anymore in JUnit 5, so the `ErrorCollector` solutions don't work anymore. The built-in option in JUnit5 is `Assertions.assertAll` which isn't covered by any of those answers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks - I see now how dramatically things have changed ([`"@Rule` and `@ClassRule` no longer exist"](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use JUnit5's [assertAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll(java.lang.String,java.util.Collection)).

For example:

```java
@Test
public void unitForTest_SomeScenario_ShouldReturn() {
    String name = "y";
    assertAll(
            () -> assertThat(name).isNotNull(),
            () -> assertThat(name).isEqualTo("x"), // failed assert
            () -> assertThat(name).isEqualTo("y"),
            () -> assertThat(name).isEqualTo("z") // failed assert
    );
}
```

Will fail with the following detailed response:

```
Expecting:
 <"y">
to be equal to:
 <"x">
but was not.
Comparison Failure: 
Expected :x
Actual   :y
<Click to see difference>


Expecting:
 <"y">
to be equal to:
 <"z">
but was not.
Comparison Failure: 
Expected :z
Actual   :y
<Click to see difference>

org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
```

Note: as some of the comments on your question imply this *might* be better expressed by using separate tests (rather than one test with multiple assertions) however, as long as the multiple assertions are part of a single 'conceptual assertion' then I can definitely see a case for using `assertAll`.