# Why aren't my `assertEquals` statements all displaying something?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

The following is a snippet from my JUnit5 test class.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("This is just a simple JUnit 5 test")
void testSimple() {
    assertEquals(2, 3, "this is the 1st assertEquals");
    assertEquals(4, 5, "this is the 2nd assertEquals");
    assertEquals(5, 6, "this is the 3rd asswerEquals");
}
```

However, when I run this, I only manage to get the first assert statement to show the message. As all of them clearly fail, shouldn't they all be showing their respective messages?

Comment: No, the first one fails, then the others are not reached / executed.

Comment: Aah, okay! Would you mind pointing me to any relevant reference documentation online? Much appreciated.

Comment: "Unless otherwise noted, a failed assertion will throw an AssertionFailedError or a subclass thereof." https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you... But I can't seem to be able to find the part which states that if the first assert fails, then the others won't be reached.

Comment: @Grateful if it throws an exception the rest of the code method will be skipped, just like any other exception.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh yes, of course! Unless there is a try and catch block to handle it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I believe any assertion error short-circuits everything... Nothing following a failed assertion executes in that particular test case; you simply just get booted!

Comment: You could use [`assertAll(...)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll(org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable...)). However, generally unrelated assertions are better done as individual tests, or parameterized tests.

Comment: Again, thank you to all who have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As highlighted in the comments section above, an exception is thrown if `assertEquals` fails. This prevents any following statements from being reached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [assertAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll(java.lang.String,java.util.Collection)) to assert all tests together:

```
Assertions.assertAll(
            "heading",
            () -> assertEquals(2, 3, "this is the 1st assertEquals"),
            () -> assertEquals(4, 5, "this is the 2nd assertEquals"),
            () -> assertEquals(5, 6, "this is the 3rd assertEquals")
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

Normally, JUnit will not continue the test after the first failing assertion was encountered. There are a few reasons for this, the most important (IMHO) are:

- If one assertion fails, it's likely for the subsequent ones to fail as well. Anyway, the whole test will be considered as failing.
- Possible (but not mandatorily), your fist assertions can set up things for the following ones and/or check their prerequisites.

If you need to continue your tests even after a failed assiertion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929661/junit-5-run-all-assert-even-if-there-is-failed-one) for an answer showing how to achieve this. Anyway, the following other tests (new `@Test` annotated methods) will continue to be executed anyway.

**Edit:**

Highlighted test vs. assertion difference.

Comment: @luk2302, sorry, but I disagree. What I wrote was exactly about failing assertions. I tried to point this one out a little more by editing the answer, but I think, it was already quite comprehensible before. Succeeding tests will continue after a failure, assertions within the same test normally won't.